# Format of SMS messages in 226660312ssm.sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, sms, firefox-os

I downloaded the SMS database off a [developer phone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeeksPhone_Keon) with Firefox OS 1.3:

```
adb pull /data/local/storage/persistent/chrome/idb/226660312ssm.sqlite
```

Then I ran with [SqliteBrowser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/):

```
SELECT data FROM object_data WHERE ID = 8;
```

See screenshot below. The result is a blob, which - when viewed as text - contains fragments of an SMS message, interspersed with non-human readable characters. In order to decode the blob, I would like to know:

*What format is the blob in?*

[image: Screenshot of blob viewed as text]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question. Based on the [source](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/master/dom/mobilemessage/src/gonk/MobileMessageDB.jsm) it's an indexedDB database. This is internally mapped to sqlite. As far as I can see we don't serialize this stuff ourselves, so this is all in the IDB layer; so I guess it serializes JS objects and then stores it into one record.

Some solutions I can think of:

- If possible, query the [mozMobileMessageApi](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator.mozMobileMessage),
- Get a way to import sqlite files into indexedDB (I don't think there would be a standard solution to this as the internals are browser specific)
- Create a page on a new domain, create an indexedDB database, replace the sqlite file on your desktop computer by the SMS sqlite file, and then query from the browser
- Dig through the IDB serialization code, which lives [here](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/tree/master/dom/indexedDB)